# WSOD on administration pages

Tags: 6, wsod

Here are the facts:

- Made a clean install of Drupal 6.20
- Installed and enabled [Admin Menu](http://drupal.org/node/901356) module

From this point on I can't access any `admin/*` page however I can access to both `node/*` and `user/*`...

PHP log:

```
No entries
```

Apache error log:

```
No entries
```

Apache access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2011:16:22:16 +0000] "GET /drupal_testes/ HTTP/1.0" 200 5771
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2011:16:22:14 +0000] "GET /drupal_testes/admin HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

DB table watchdog:

```
Nothing serious...
```

And that's all, for a single access to `/drupal_testes/admin`...
Disabling admin_menu (at the system table) does work. Also, as a side note, when I go to `admin/build/modules` and try to enable Admin Menu again the page will take forever to load and end in a WSOD.
After that if I go to `drupal_testes/node` the admin_menu is active and working, except for the `admin/*` pages.

I'm aware of [WSOD Walkthrough](http://drupal.org/node/158043) but none of the reasons seems to apply this case..
Any idea why can this be happening?

---

**Edit #4**

- Exactly the same behaviour when installing [Token](http://drupal.org/node/934902)

**Edit #5**

- Installing CCK, which in theory is much heavier than Token or Admin Menu, presents no problems.
- Flushing the `cache_*` tables changes nothing.
- Increasing php.ini `memory_limit` didn't make any difference...

---

Although the problem is solved by disabling the offending modules, the goal is to have them active and working properly...

Comment: Fully documented article about WSOD: [The White Screen of Death (Completely Blank Page)](http://drupal.org/node/158043)

Comment: why a downvote? setting the devel error reporting in the index.php is the best practice to bebug a wsod.

Comment: "I'm aware of WSOD Walkthrough but none of the reasons seems to apply this case.." have you added the error reporting in the index.php? Do you get some errors then?

Comment: @Nikit, that isn't helpful at all. I said I was aware of it in the OP and nothing in there applied/helped this case.

Comment: @DaNieL, yes, I did. No errors. Just a long wait for the page to load and a final WSOD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just started a new site / doesn't contain any data yet as you seem to indicate in your question, it may be faster to reinstall Drupal than search for the source of the WSOD.

---

Otherwise, you could have a look in the database directly:

- first, check the **watchdog table**: it may have error messages that don't show up in Apache and PHP logs
- then, **empty the caches** by truncating every table named `cache_something`
- then if you're sure this module is the one that caused the problem, you can **edit the list of enabled modules** in table `system`: find the module in the list and change its `status to "0"`

But if you make any modification directly in the database, make sure to save a backup first, just in case ;-)

Comment: Uops, forgot to mention it: there are no errors @ watchdog. Thanks for the other advices, will check those now.

Comment: About the second point, empty all cache_something table except cache_form. That's not actually a cache but contains build information about forms. It doesn't matter for a new/development site, but it would for example invalidate all forms that users are currently filling out somewhere, so don't delete that on a production site.

Comment: @Berdir Ah yes, good point

Comment: Well, since the only thing that really worked was to reinstall.. You'll get the rep. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PHP memory limit is set to 32 MB (or greater), and that you have output buffering enabled.

Comment: I actually set my memory_limit to 62M in development and adjust it up or down as needed.

Comment: I would recommend setting it to 256 MB if you can just to see if this is the issue, you can always bring it down later

Comment: I had my memory_limit = 16M. But increasing the value changed nothing. Good effort though.

Comment: Check if output buffering is enabled and a buffer handler has been set. Core doesn't require it, but some modules do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what is happening in your case, but a BOM signature present before the starting `<?php` is difficult to be seen. I had a problem with a module, and it came out that the WSOD was caused by the BOM signature added by the editor I was using, which then didn't show when I edited the file with my usual editor. I then discovered that the editor was set to add the BOM signature by default.

There are also some Unicode characters that have a purpose similar to a space, but they are not show on some editors. This happened to me too, and I was not able to understand the reason of the WSOD until I didn't post the content of the file in a forum, and used Firefox to see that forum page.